# standalone order of magnitude and explicit \pm zero with siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am facing two problems since I updated to the newer version of siunitx:

1. I am unable to write a standalone order of magnitude with a unit.
2. I want to write plus minus zero explicitly.

I have attached my MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{uncertainty-mode=separate}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty-units = single}
\begin{document}
What it looks when I type: \qty{e4}{\tonne}.\par
What I want it to look like: \ensuremath{10^4}~\unit{\tonne}.\par

What it looks when I type: \qty{12.51(00)}{\meter}.\par
What I want it to look like:
\ensuremath{12.51 \pm 0.0}~\unit{\meter}.
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:
[image: Output of the minimal working code]

Comment: For future questions: It is best to ask for only one thing per question. This makes it easier for other people having one of your wishes to find the question, for people who know how to solve one of your problems to answer, and for site mechanics such as marking as duplicate to work.

Comment: Apologies. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```latex
\sisetup{
  print-unity-mantissa=false,
  retain-zero-uncertainty=true,
}
```

The zero-uncertainty is printed as "0.00" instead of "0.0", which is consistent with the number of digits of the value it belongs to.